# Jquery uncheck checkboxes siblings on check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have just one checkbox checked at the same time.
I would like to have the value checked.

It works if I remove all div tag but I need to have div tag for the organisation.

So my js code :

```
$('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log("value = "+value);
  });
```

And my html code which works without div but not with div :

```
<div id="id_1" class='class_1'>

  <div id="id_a" class='class_a'>
    <div>
      <img src="fr.png">
      <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="fr" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="cs.png">
      <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="cs" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="en.png">
      <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="en" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="id_b" class='class_b'>
    <div>
      <img src="bc.png">
      <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="bc" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="tl.png">
      <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="tl" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="jk.png">
      <input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="jk" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
   $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
   $(this).prop('checked') ? $(this).prop('checked', false) : $(this).prop('checked', true);
   var value = $(this).val();
   console.log("value = "+value);
});
```

Comment: thank's it works well.
I forgot something in my question but your code work !
I would like to have just one selected box in all of the page, not 1 in class_a and an other one in class_b but only one in all page !
So your answer works
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You current situation is perfect candidate for use of radios instead, you need to group them by name:

```
<div id="id_1" class='class_1'>

  <div id="id_a" class='class_a'>
    <div>
      <img src="fr.png">
      <input type="radio" name='langa' class="myRadio" value="fr" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="cs.png">
      <input type="radio" name='langa' class="myRadio" value="cs" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="en.png">
      <input type="radio" name='langa' class="myRadio" value="en" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="id_b" class='class_b'>
    <div>
      <img src="bc.png">
      <input type="radio" name='langb' class="myRadio" value="bc" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="tl.png">
      <input type="radio" name='langb' class="myRadio" value="tl" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="jk.png">
      <input type="radio" name='langb' class="myRadio" value="jk" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Then you can use this script:

```
$('.myRadio').change(function() {
   var value = $(this).val(); // this will get you the checked radio value.
   console.log("value = "+value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define  checkboxes with same name like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" value="bc" name="common_name" />
```

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't address the actual issue the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

First find the parent siblings then:

```
$('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition checkboxes are used when you want to give the option to select multiple options to the user. If you want him to select only one value use radios instead :)

Example -

```
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
```

But if this has to be done by checkboxes you can try this :)

```
<input type = "checkbox" name = "sample" value = "1">firsr
<input type = "checkbox" name = "sample" value = "2">second
<input type = "checkbox" name = "sample" value = "3">third
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name=sample]').click(function(e){

$( "input[name=sample]").prop('checked', false);
$(this).attr('checked','checked')
})
});
```